# Get Feature Symbol

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I am using this code to get the symbol associated with a feature:

```
IFeature feature = geoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.GetFeature( geoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.FeatureClassID );
geoFeatureLayer.Renderer.get_SymbolByFeature( feature );
```

Of course, now I have encountered a layer where "FeatureClassID = -1" and this code crashes with "ROW_NOT_FOUND."
The help says: "...IFeatureClass::FeatureClassID will always return -1 for Coverage and Shapefile feature classes."
I (sort of) understand that but how should I get the Symbol for that kind of feature?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass an objectID to [IFeatureClass.GetFeature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetFeature_Method/0025000002t5000000/), not a ClassID.

Comment: Where do I get the ObjectId?  The help says, "Since IFeatureClass inherits from IObjectClass, you can also get the feature class ID from IObjectClass:: ObjectClassID." But that is -1 also.

Comment: A featureclass contains a collection of features.  When you draw a map the map calls ILayer.Draw.  For a featurelayer it will loop through each feature in the featureclass and for each feature get its symbol and draw it.  You can use a FeatureCursor to get features.

Comment: Aaaah! Doh! I need a feature so I grab the first one that a featureCursor returns and that works! Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to call ReleaseComObject on the cursor when done with it.